# Accidentally deleted Wired connection

Tags: networking, 18.04

it was here in the list below, I right clicked on it and then deleted it

[image]

Comment: I am afraid you will have to recreate it, if this was your question.

Comment: ok. Not a biggy, but how? (I have an ethernet cable pluged in as we speak)

Comment: Do you see a plus sign below the connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Kubuntu (judging from the screenshot), if you see a screen like that:
[image]

you have to click on the plus sign to add the connections.

Comment: I did not see the + sign (I had to scroll down to it)!